# httponly cookie not available in subsequent xhr requests

Tags: xmlhttprequest, xss, csrf, redux, axios

#### Background

I have a restful backend, React + Redux frontend and I'm trying to protect against CSRF and XSS attacks.

The frontend requests a CSRF token from the API. The API response sets the CSRF token in a HttpOnly cookie and also in the response body. The redux reducer saves the token (from the response body) to the redux store.

If I request the token in the main container's `componentDidMount()`, everything works, but the concern is this is a one shot. Instead, as the requests to the API go through a custom middleware, I would prefer the middleware to request the CSRF token if it doesn't exist locally.

#### Issue

The flow is as follows (Tested on Chrome 50 and Firefox 47):

1. CSRF token requested. Token stored in HttpOnly cookie and redux store
2. Original API call requested with `X-CSRF-Token` header set. **cookie not sent**
3. Receive 403 from API due to missing cookie. API responds with **new HttpOnly cookie**. The Javascript can't see this cookie, so the redux store is not updated.
4. Additional API calls requested with X-CSRF-Token header from step 2. and cookie from step 3.
5. Receive 403 due to mismatched cookie vs X-CSRF-Token

If I add a delay before step 2 with `window.setTimeout`, the cookie is still not sent, so I don't *think* it's a race condition with the browser not having enough time to save the cookie?

**Action Creator**

```
const login = (credentials) => {

    return {
        type: AUTH_LOGIN,
        payload: {
            api: {
                method: 'POST',
                url: api.v1.auth.login,
                data: credentials
            }
        }
    };
};
```

**Middleware**

```
/**
 * Ensure the crumb and JWT authentication token are wrapped in all requests to the API.
 */
export default (store) => (next) => (action) => {

    if (action.payload && action.payload.api) {

        store.dispatch({ type: `${action.type}_${PENDING}` });
        return ensureCrumb(store)
            .then((crumb) => {

                const state = store.getState();
                const requestConfig = {
                    ...action.payload.api,
                    withCredentials: true,
                    xsrfCookieName: 'crumb',
                    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRF-Token',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-Token': crumb
                    }
                };

                if (state.auth.token) {
                    requestConfig.headers = { ...requestConfig.headers, Authorization: `Bearer ${state.auth.token}` };
                }

                return axios(requestConfig);
            })
            .then((response) => store.dispatch({ type:`${action.type}_${SUCCESS}`, payload: response.data }))
            .catch((response) => store.dispatch({ type: `${action.type}_${FAILURE}`, payload: response.data }));
    }

    return next(action);
};

/**
 * Return the crumb if it exists, otherwise requests a crumb
 * @param store - The current redux store
 * @returns Promise - crumb token
 */
const ensureCrumb = (store) => {

    const state = store.getState();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        if (state.crumb.token) {
            return resolve(state.crumb.token);
        }

        store.dispatch({ type: CRUMB_PENDING });
        axios.get(api.v1.crumb)
            .then((response) => {

                store.dispatch({ type: CRUMB_SUCCESS, payload: { token: response.data.crumb } });
                window.setTimeout(() => resolve(response.data.crumb), 10000);
                // return resolve(response.data.crumb);
            })
            .catch((error) => {

                store.dispatch({ type: CRUMB_FAILURE });
                return reject(error);
            });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused because I was creating a new axios client on each request, if I reuse the same axios client for all API requests, the cookie is saved correctly and used in subsequent requests.